# nightwatch - find current page object

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

Is there a way to find the current page object within a custom command.

I call the getElementCount(), while the page PageObejct1 is instantiated.

```
    browser.page.PageObejct1()
      .getElementCount('@clickToSelectList', function (count) {
       //Some code
       }
```

The custom command on the other hand tries to find out the current locateStrategy.

```
        module.exports.command = function (tag, callback) {
        
         //Here distinction between PageObejct1 and PageObejct2
          var selector = this.page.PageObejct2(tag);
          var locateStrategy =  selector.locateStrategy;
          //Some code again.
        };
```

Anyway, my issue is that the page PageObejct1 and the page PageObejct2 represent two different page objects. Therefore, I would like to have a generic solution. Something like an interface in OOP.

Would that be possible?
Or is it possible to get the current page object from nightwatch somehow?

Comment: what is tag's purpose ?

Comment: It is just an selector, e.g. @selector